# Distribute evenly vertically without flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to make my site IE9 compatible but I am using flex boxes in lots of places so I need an alternate method for evenly spacing child elements.

My design is responsive so I need the same effect as flexbox where I can evenly space elements but I am not sure how to do it.

Here is a snippet to show how I am using flexbox in my layout.

```css
#container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.ele1, .ele2, .ele3{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.ele1{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.ele2{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.ele3{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="ele1"></div>
  <div class="ele2"></div>
  <div class="ele3"></div>
</div>
```

How do I do this without flexbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a flex box polyfil https://github.com/10up/flexibility

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which is a pure JavaScript (it also supports jQuery), as there are no CSS equivalent, if you do/can not use `flexbox`.

Comment: Is there any masonary fallback/polyfill for flexbox?  So I could conditionally load a js file only on IE8/9 that would take care of the flex for me?  I looked but couldn't find one so I am a little undecided what to do.  I checked my analytics and 8.2% of my traffic is on IE8 so I need to do something about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` in percentages. The distribution is roughly dependant upon how tall each box is. I estimated that there's a total of 10% vertical space inside the container that comprises of padding and borders. That leaves 90% to distribute between the inside walls of the container and between themselves.

```css
#container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  /*display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;*/
}

.ele1, .ele2, .ele3{
  /*flex: 0 0 auto;*/
  
}

.ele1{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10% 0 15%;
}
.ele2{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
    margin: 25% 0 15%;
}
.ele3{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 25% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="ele1"></div>
  <div class="ele2"></div>
  <div class="ele3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: She/he wants to change an entire design, not a simple layout, and I believe the provided snippets is just an example

Comment: OP: *so I need an alternate method for evenly spacing child elements.* But asking for an entire design change would be a better question since having fixed dimensions will severely hinder responsiveness.

Comment: I tried this approach also but the margin doesn't resize responsively.  It only works with a fixed layout and then if the layout is fixed I could just used a fixed numerical value for position anyway.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: To be truly responsive you need to use relative lengths (not on everything of course) and media queries.  Start on the mobile aspect first then work your way to the desktop.